# What is a statistical test I can use to show that, between Model A and Model B, Model A can be better distinguished from some Dataset X?

Tags: modeling, dataset, goodness-of-fit, curve-fitting

I have a dataset (Dataset X) with error bars. I have two different models (Model A and Model B) which each try to fit the dataset. On visual inspection, it is very obvious that Model A fits Dataset X much better than Model B.

I have also computed the root-mean square (R.M.S.) misfit between Model A and Dataset X (0.94 R.M.S.) and Model B and Dataset X (2.11 R.M.S.).

However, what I am looking for is some statistical measure showing the *amount of difference* between these two R.M.S. values. I feel like a simple "Difference in R.M.S." (i.e. $2.11 - 0.94 = d$) is not really a valid measure.

Any other suggestions?

Note: I am not statistician and have a very limited background in statistics.

Comment: R.M.S.?  Root mean square?  You should spell out all acronyms on their first use to avoid confusion.